# How to register JS engines - reactjs.net in .NET framework 4.6 - Server Error - Microsoft.ClearScript.ScriptEngineException?

Tags: c#, reactjs.net

I am trying to make a simple reactjs.net simple application. I have installed React.Web.Mvc4 through NuGet manager. This is a MVC application and I am trying to render a Index view from the HomeController.

I have tried adding the chakra and V8 engine. Also, I have changed the ReactConfig.js to include -

```
ReactSiteConfiguration.Configuration.AddScript("~/Scripts/App.js");
JsEngineSwitcher.Current.DefaultEngineName = V8JsEngine.EngineName;
JsEngineSwitcher.Current.EngineFactories.AddV8();
```

However, I get the different error -

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: Microsoft.ClearScript.ScriptEngineException: SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

Source Error: 


Line 7:  
Line 8:  <!-- Reach Component -->
Line 9:  @Html.React("Hello", new
Line 10: {
Line 11:
```

Index.cshtml

```
@using React.Web.Mvc
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<!-- Reach Component -->
@Html.React("Hello", new
{

})
```

and

Scripts/App.js

```
class Hello extends React.component {
    render() {
        return (<h1>Hello React App</h1>);
    }

}
```

Now, in the App_Start - 
ReactConfig.js

```
public static class ReactConfig
    {
        public static void Configure()
        {



    ReactSiteConfiguration.Configuration.AddScript("~/Scripts/App.js");

        }
    }
```

The http://localhost:65386/Home/Index should display -

"Hello React App"

Answer (score 0):

```
using JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.ChakraCore;
using JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Core;
using JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Jint;
using JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Jurassic;
using JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Msie;
using JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.NiL;
using JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.V8;
using JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Vroom;

namespace JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Sample.AspNet45.Mvc5
{
    public class JsEngineSwitcherConfig
    {
        public static void Configure(IJsEngineSwitcher engineSwitcher)
        {
            engineSwitcher.EngineFactories
                .AddChakraCore()
                .AddJint()
                .AddJurassic()
                .AddMsie(new MsieSettings
                {
                    EngineMode = JsEngineMode.ChakraIeJsRt
                })
                .AddNiL()
                .AddV8()
                .AddVroom()
                ;

            engineSwitcher.DefaultEngineName = ChakraCoreJsEngine.EngineName;
        }
    }
}
```

For Further clarification, Check this link [github](https://github.com/Taritsyn/JavaScriptEngineSwitcher/wiki/Registration-of-JS-engines)